# User data via Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a client that is curious about creating a custom app, tapping into Facebook's API. They want to pull user data about their page followers (age, location, interests etc) and compare it to other public pages and their followers.

I'm looking for some help understanding what the limitations are with Facebook's API. Do you need to be admin of a page to gain app authorization, to then access your follower's information? Or is it public via graph search and can happen on any page and / or user?

Answer (score 2):

It´s more a data/privacy issue anyway, but you can´t get the list of Page fans with the API. For comparison, you can use the Page Insights. There is also an API if you want to automate things: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/page